# Passing struct pointers to functions

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, struct, structure, declaration

Hey I'm having trouble understanding on how structs get passed to functions as pointers because i want to modify my structs later in my project. So I'm creating a game that has rooms and this function creates a 2d array of the world. I'm passing in struct room and struct World because I'm storing each room in a cord in World struct which is a 2d array. When i got print out each room, it doesn't print anything out and i think the problem is with my pointers.

So my first function that's in a struct array that will hold all the rooms and it initializes each room to the array. Then i try to print out each rooms number but it doesn't print anything.

Second function creates my 2d world, its gonna be 3x3 world. Which puts a room onto the World cords

```
struct room
{
    int roomNum;
    int creaturesTotal;
    char description[50];
    char cleanOrdirty[20];
};

int main()
{
    int MaxRooms = 8;
    int rows = 2;
    int cols = 2;
    //creaste each room
    struct room Room1;
    struct room Room2;
    struct room Room3;
    struct room Room4;
    struct room Room5;
    struct room Room6;
    struct room Room7;
    struct room Room8;
    struct room Room9;
    struct PC player;
    player.respect = 40;

    //Store them into a array
    struct room AllRooms[MaxRooms];
    AllRooms[0] = Room1;
    AllRooms[1] = Room2;
    AllRooms[2] = Room3;
    AllRooms[3] = Room4;
    AllRooms[4] = Room5;
    AllRooms[5] = Room6;
    AllRooms[6] = Room7;
    AllRooms[7] = Room8;
    AllRooms[8] = Room9;

    struct room World[rows][cols];

    createRooms(AllRooms);

    //create the world
    createWorld(AllRooms,rows,cols,World);

    struct PC cords[rows][cols];
    player = startPointPC(&player,rows,cols,&World,&cords);
}



void createRooms(struct room* AllRooms[])
{
    int MaxRooms = 8;
    int number = 1;
    for(int i = 0;i <= MaxRooms; i++)
    {
        AllRooms[i]->roomNum = number;
        number++;
    }
    for(int i = 0;i <= MaxRooms; i++)
    {
        printf("%d",AllRooms[i]->roomNum);
    }

}

//creates the 2d world
void createWorld(struct room* AllRooms[], int rows, int cols, struct room* World[rows][cols])
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= cols; j++)
        {
            World[i][j] = AllRooms[counter];
            counter++;
            printf("\nWorld %d", World[i][j]->roomNum);
        }

    }
}

    struct PC startPointPC(struct PC* player,int rows, int cols, struct room* 
    World[rows][cols],struct PC* cords[rows][cols])
    {

       int x = 0;
       int y = 0;

       player->x = x;
       player->y = y;

       //cords[x][y] = player;
       printf("\nYou are starting in Room %d",World[x][y]->roomNum);

       return player;

}
```

Comment: Haven't looked any more closely than to see that you're calling `createRooms` with `struct room AllRooms[]` instead of how you're declaring `createRooms`, which is that it is to receive `struct room* AllRooms[]`.

Comment: To put it differently, `createRooms()` is expecting an array of pointers to rooms, but you're sending it an array of rooms.

Comment: Sorry im still a little confused, I just started using C so pointers are new to me, your saying to make my array a pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement

```
AllRooms[8] = Room9;
```

accesses a memory beyond the array that has elements in the range `[0, MaxRooms).`

Moreover such an assignment like for example this

```
AllRooms[0] = Room1;
```

can invoke undefined behavior because the object Room1 was not initialized and its integer data members can have trap values.

You created a one-dimensional array

```
struct room AllRooms[MaxRooms];
```

and passed it as an argument to the function `createRooms`

createRooms(AllRooms);

Arrays designator in expressions (with rare exceptions) are converted to pointers to their first elements.

So in fact this call

createRooms(AllRooms);

is equivalent to

createRooms( &AllRooms[0] );

and the argument has the type `struct room *`.

However you declared the function that has the parameter of the type struct `room* AllRooms[]` that is adjusted by the compiler to the type `struct room **`.

The compiler should issue an error message that there is no implicit conversion from one type of the argument to other type of the function parameter.

And moreover the function shall be declared before its usage in main.

Also within the function in loops like this

for(int i = 0;i <= MaxRooms; i++)

you are using an incorrect range of indices. The valid range is `[0, MaxRooms)`

So the function should be declared and defined at least the following way

```
void createRooms( struct room AllRooms[] )
{
   int MaxRooms = 8;
   int number = 1;
   for(int i = 0;i < MaxRooms; i++)
   {
       AllRooms[i].roomNum = number;
       number++;
    }
    for(int i = 0;i < MaxRooms; i++)
    {
       printf("%d",AllRooms[i].roomNum);
    }

 }
```

Also it is a bad idea to use the local variable `MaxRooms` of the function

```
   int MaxRooms = 8;
```

instead of passing a corresponding argument that specifies the size of the array.

Similar problems exist for the function createWorld.

It should be declared and defined like

```
void createWorld( struct room AllRooms[], int rows, int cols, struct room World[rows][cols])
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            World[i][j] = AllRooms[counter];
            counter++;
            printf("\nWorld %d", World[i][j].roomNum);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to change the -> to the dot since its not passing in an pointer?

Comment: @NazarTrut Thanks. That was a typo due to "copy and paste".:)

Comment: I have a question since i see your good at this, if i would want to modify a structs parameters through an function, would i have to use pointers?

Comment: @NazarTrut If you just pass a single struct, you have to use a pointer. But if you pass an array, it's automatically converted to a pointer.

Comment: @NazarTrut If you want to change an original object in a function you have to pass it by reference. In C it means passing through a pointer to an object. When you are passing an array then the array designator is converted to pointer to its first element. So in fact all elements of an array are passed by reference. If you are passing a single object then you have to pass a pointer to the object.

Comment: ok thank you, if i want to return a struct that i modified in a function, how would i do that? im trying that right now and my error is incompatible types when returning type

Comment: @NazarTrut Just declare the return type as the type of the structure.

Comment: Its not working for me, i edited my post, I add the function I'm working on, the function is startPointPC which gives the cords for the player to start, I'm still getting an error

Comment: @NazarTrut Please do not edit your question. Create a new one. Otherwise your question will confuse readers of the question and answers.

Comment: @NazarTrut The returned value and the return type of the appended by you function are different. Either return the same type as the type of the returned object or dereference the returned value.

Comment: hmm but How is it different? my functions header is struct PC, I'm returning a PC struct and I'm initializing it to a Struct PC too, where am i wrong here?

Comment: @NazarTrut You are returning player that declared like struct PC* player that is a pointer. But the return type is not a pointer type. It is struct PC.