# Modifying and returning a struct in a function

Tags: c

I'm creating a game that creates a 2d map with cords and each cord is a room. So I'm creating a player that starts in cords (0,0) which is Room 1 in my game. I'm trying to return the player that holds the cords and this is where my problem is. I'm getting a incompatible types when returning type 'struct PC * ' but 'struct PC' was expected.

World is my 2d map that holds each room with its cords, and cords is the players cords.

```
struct PC
{
   int respect;
   int x;
   int y;

};

void createRooms(struct room AllRooms[])
{
   int MaxRooms = 9;
   int number = 1;
for(int i = 0;i < MaxRooms; i++)
{
    AllRooms[i].roomNum = number;
    number++;
}
for(int i = 0;i < MaxRooms; i++)
{
    printf("%d",AllRooms[i].roomNum);
}

}

void createWorld(struct room AllRooms[], int rows, int cols, struct room World[rows][cols])
{
  int counter = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i <= rows;i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j <= cols; j++)
    {
        World[i][j] = AllRooms[counter];
        counter++;
        printf("\nWorld %d", World[i][j].roomNum);
    }

  }

}

struct PC startPointPC(struct PC* player,int rows, int cols, struct room* World[rows][cols],struct PC* cords[rows][cols])
{

   int x = 0;
   int y = 0;

   player->x = x;
   player->y = y;

   cords[x][y] = player;
   printf("\nYou are starting in Room %d",World[x][y]->roomNum);

   return player;

}

int main()
{
   int MaxRooms = 9;
    int rows = 2;
    int cols = 2;
    //creaste each room
    struct room Room1;
    struct room Room2;
    struct room Room3;
    struct room Room4;
    struct room Room5;
    struct room Room6;
    struct room Room7;
    struct room Room8;
    struct room Room9;
    struct PC player;
    player.respect = 40;

     //Store them into a array
     struct room AllRooms[MaxRooms];
     AllRooms[0] = Room1;
     AllRooms[1] = Room2;
     AllRooms[2] = Room3;
     AllRooms[3] = Room4;
     AllRooms[4] = Room5;
     AllRooms[5] = Room6;
     AllRooms[6] = Room7;
     AllRooms[7] = Room8;
     AllRooms[8] = Room9;

    //allrooms has all the 9 rooms in the array
   createRooms(AllRooms);

   struct PC player;
   struct room World[rows][cols];
   struct PC cords[rows][cols];

   player = startPointPC(&player,rows,cols,&World,&cords);

}
```

Comment: Why do you need to return the player? You passed a pointer and modified it in place. But if you really want to do it, you need `return *player;`

Comment: ok thank you, but when i go to print the cords, it doesnt print anything out but i'm getting no errors.

Comment: You're assigning `cords[x][y]` but printing `World[x][y]`.

Comment: Also, `cords` is declared as an array of `struct PC`, but you're trying to assign a pointer to the element.

Comment: It should be `struct PC *cords[rows][cols]`. And you don't need to use `&` when passing an array to a function, it automatically converts to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`cords` should be an array of pointers, not an array of structures. The same with `World`.

There's no need to return anything from `startPointPC`, since it modifies the structure in place.

Don't use `&` when passing an array to a function. Arrays are automatically converted to pointers when used as function arguments.

Your code is printing the contents of `World[x][y]`, but never initializes it. But none of the `struct room` code is in the question, I assume you just left this out to simplify it.

```
void startPointPC(struct PC* player,int rows, int cols, struct room* World[rows][cols],struct PC* cords[rows][cols])
{

   int x = 0;
   int y = 0;

   player->x = x;
   player->y = y;

   cords[x][y] = player;
   printf("\nYou are starting in Room %d",World[x][y]->roomNum);
}

int main()
{
   struct PC player;
   struct room *World[rows][cols];
   struct PC *cords[rows][cols];

   startPointPC(&player,rows,cols,World,cords);
}
```

Comment: ok thank  you, i added my other functions because i think its something wrong with my createWorld function, because even with you changes its not printing the contents of World

Comment: I assuming maybe i have to use a Struct room pointer for World because im initializing it?

Comment: Isn't the other stuff the same as your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977531/passing-struct-pointers-to-functions